# Add attribute to edge in projected graph

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I have a DataFrame that resembles an affiliation matrix. I have a person, an event and the year of the event.

```
d = {'person' : ['1', '2', '3', '1', '4', '3', '4', '1', '2'],
    'event' : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D'],
    'year' : [1995, 1995, 1995, 1996, 1996, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

I need to get the first meeting between two persons. That is, if '1' and '2' met at event 'A' and 'D', I need to know when they met for the first time (in this example, it was in 'A' in 1995).

I do not know if this is possible using NetworkX or if I need to do it in some other way using Pandas. How can I do this?

I can get to the projected network but I do not know how to transfer the attribute 'year' to the edges of that projected network. It is important to note that the attribute ('year' in this case) is an attribute of the event so it is constant for all the edges of each event.

This is what I have so far:

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd

d = {'person' : ['1', '2', '3', '1', '4', '3', '4', '1', '2'],
     'event' : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D'],
     'year' : [1995, 1995, 1995, 1996, 1996, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

B = nx.from_pandas_dataframe(df, 'person', 'event', edge_attr='year')

G = nx.bipartite.projected_graph(B, df.person.unique(), multigraph = True)
```

Comment: I corrected a mistake in my original answer. I sorted in the wrong place, but it should be good now. Let me know if this doesn't fit your use case.

Comment: @3novak Thanks! It works well. I wonder how this is going to perform in a large  dataset. I created a way doing merges instead of iterating. Maybe I can rephrase the question so it can be solved with your answer. Maybe you can add the libraries that need to be imported.

Comment: Good point, @frmo. I added the itertools library import statement. Could you share your merge solution? I'm curious how it works. Could you explain what you mean about rephrasing the question so it can be solved with the method I proposed?

Comment: @3novak I was thinking about removing the NetworkX parts so it is a more general questions that can be solved with your proposed solution. The merge way is df.merge(df, on='event', how='outer') and then you just need to drop the repeated dyads (i.e. order does not matter). Finally, add the year to the events and sort. I guess I could share the complete solution if I rephrase the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar enough with NetworkX to help you with the problem of adding edge attributes, but this method does identify the first meeting of individuals.

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools

# initial data
d = {'person' : ['1', '2', '3', '1', '4', '3', '4', '1', '2'],
     'event' : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D'],
     'year' : [1995, 1995, 1995, 1996, 1996, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

# create a unique list of individuals for each meeting. this should be
# unique anyway, but just in case. :)
# note that this approach is also robust to events in different years
# sharing the same name.

grpd = df.groupby(['year', 'event'])['person'].unique().apply(lambda x: sorted(x))

# sort based on the year from the oldest meetings to the most recent
grpd.sort_index(ascending=False, inplace=True)

# we'll add meetings to a dictionary and overwrite as encounter more
# recent meetings

meetings = {}

for idx in range(len(grpd)):
    year = grpd.index[idx][0]
    meeting = grpd.index[idx][1]
    for combo in itertools.combinations(grpd[idx], 2):
        meetings[combo] = (meeting, year)


import pprint

>>> pprint.pprint(meetings)
{('1', '2'): ('A', 1995),
 ('1', '3'): ('A', 1995),
 ('1', '4'): ('B', 1996),
 ('2', '3'): ('A', 1995),
 ('3', '4'): ('C', 2000)
```